# .Net 5 Dockerize "/ChatCase.Domain/ChatCase.Domain.csproj" not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am new for dockerize a .Net Core project. I have been working on dockerizing my project, but when I build it, it returns an error.

How can I fix this?

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY ["ChatCase.Api/ChatCase.Api.csproj", "ChatCase.Api/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Framework/ChatCase.Framework.csproj", "ChatCase.Framework/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Business/ChatCase.Business.csproj", "ChatCase.Business/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Repository/ChatCase.Repository.csproj", "ChatCase.Repository/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Core/ChatCase.Core.csproj", "ChatCase.Core/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Common/ChatCase.Common.csproj", "ChatCase.Common/"]
    COPY ["ChatCase.Domain/ChatCase.Domain.csproj", "ChatCase.Domain/"]
    RUN dotnet restore "ChatCase.Api/ChatCase.Api.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/ChatCase.Api"
    RUN dotnet build "ChatCase.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "ChatCase.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ChatCase.Api.dll"]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd C:\Projects\ChatCase
docker build . -f ChatCase.API/Dockerfile -t chatcase
```